# ReactDOM.findDOMNode() return null with refs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-dom

ReactDOM is not working with refs.

I want to sting html `<b>abcd</b>` append to body of modal, but it's not working.

when I check `console.log()` of `modal` and `modalBody`, it return `null`.

My code in under:

```
class Header extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            this.state.modalSendResult: false
        };
      }

      _open() {
        this.setState({
           modal: !this.state.modal
        });
        if (!this.state.modal) {
           this.appendNode();
        }
      }

      appendNode() {
        let modal = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.modal)
            modalBody = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.body);
        ReactDOM.render(
          <b>abcde</b>, modalBody
        );
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Button onClick={this._open.bind(this)}
                  className="btn btn-primary btn-primary-1 mr-1">
               <i className="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Open
          </Button>
          <Modal ref="modal" isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this._open}
                            className={'modal-primary modal_customer'}>
               <ModalHeader toggle={this._open}>
                    Danh sách kết quả gửi
               </ModalHeader>
               <ModalBody className="modal-send" ref="body">
               </ModalBody>
          </Modal>
        );
      } 
 }
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ReactDOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode).  You can avoid having to call `findDOMNode` by setting up your refs as specified here: [Refs and the DOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

I think in your case it would look something like

```
<Modal
  ref={(modal) => { this.modal = modal; }}
  isOpen={this.state.modal}
  toggle={this._open}
  className={'modal-primary modal_customer'}
>
  <ModalHeader toggle={this._open}>
    Danh sách kết quả gửi
  </ModalHeader>
  <ModalBody
    className="modal-send"
    ref={(body) => { this.body = body; }}
  />
</Modal>
```

Then you should be able to reference them with

```
this.modal
this.body
```

Alternatively, you could pass the content you want for your `ModalBody` component as a prop.

```
<ModalBody
  className="modal-send"
  content="abcde"
  ref={(body) => { this.body = body; }}
/>
```

And render in your `ModalBody` component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <b>{this.props.content}</b>
  );
```

Comment: This is untested, just based on what you posted

Comment: It's worked but `ReactDOM.render(<b>abcde</b>, modalBody);` show error `_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: What does your `appendNode` method look like now?  It should be something like:

`ReactDOM.render(<b>abcde</b>, this.body);`

Comment: Sorry, It my fault. `ReactDOM.render(<b>abcde</b>, this.body);` show error  `_registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

Comment: when use `document.getElementById()`, it's working well. But use `ReactDOM.render(<b>abcde</b>, this.body)`, it's not working.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative solution.  Is there a specific reason you're using `reactDOM.render` and not passing the body content as a prop?